# Transformations in JavaFx

Tags: javafx

If I wish to translate a `Node` by a displacement (10,10), then what is the difference in doing

#1.

```
myNode.setTranslateX (10); 
myNode.setTranslateY (10);
```

And Doing

#2.

```
Translate translateNode = new Translate (10,10);
myNode.getTransforms.add(translateNode);
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `adding a Translate` and `setting a translate` does the same thing. The only thing to note is that if you assigning `both to the same node` then transforms added is applied before the setting the translate/scale factor.

From the JavaDocs of [getTransforms](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getTransforms--) :

> This ObservableList of transforms is applied before translateX, translateY, scaleX, and scaleY, rotate transforms.

Comment: I had to rotate a Node about point (30,20) by 10 degrees. I have to add 3 transformations, a Translate by (30,20) then Rotate by 10 degree then another Translate by (-30,-20).

Comment: Can I do this by Node.TranslateX(),Node.TranslateY() & Node.Rotate() methods?

Comment: Is (30, 20) the translate X and Y values or the X / Y co-ordinates on your scene?

Comment: Sorry, wrong words.  I had to rotate the Node about a point at displacement of (30,20) from the Node. i.e. if scene co-ordinates of Node is (100,200), I need a rotation of 10 degrees about point (130,120).

Comment: Yes, why not. Try with `node.setTranslateX(30); node.setTranslateY(20); node.setRotate(10);`

Answer (score 0):

The first approach sets the translation absolute, wherever your node is located, after that, it will be @ x:10, y:10.

On the other hand, the second approach respects the current transformations on your node, eq myNode. So if your node was @ x:23, y:52 it'll be 33,62.